# rbenv and nokogiri errors on MacOSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, ruby-2.2

I have tried everything google has thrown at me to get my rails application running with `nokogiri`. I am running my app using ruby v2.2.7 and my ruby version is managed via rbenv.

I have followed every step here http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

I have xcode installed. But keep receiving this error when I try to boot up my rails server:

`dlopen(/Users/USER/dev/APP/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.8.1/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/libruby.2.2.0.dylib`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you also have `rvm` still activated. Try uninstalling that (`rvm implode`) and then double-checking rbenv is initialized (`which ruby` should point to a version installed in the [shimmed directory](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#understanding-shims)). After that try re-bundling in your rails project.

Comment: I started this system with `rvm`, then backed it out and uninstalled all things `rvm`. Not sure how its still floating around. RVM isn't in my path at all

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what the root problem is from the error alone, but looks like your app dependencies are located in a different ruby version directory than 2.2.7.  A few suggestions would be to check if you have the ruby version specified in your rails app's `.ruby-version` file installed via rbenv, remove the `vendor` directory in your app and rebundle, and/or removing the `.rvm` directory in your user dir.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be a long shot. Kind of a weird issue. But I do have the correct version of ruby install (2.2.7), I have no `.rvm` directory and have removed the `vendor/bundle` directory numerous times.

Comment: Ended up figuring out my problem. There was some odd gem caching going on. I removed all references to my gem cache files and rebundled everything, again, and it all started working properly

Comment: What were your exact steps? Just curious

Comment: Removing `vendor/bundler` then running `rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/bundler/ ~/.gems/cache/bundler/` and then making sure nokogiri bundles with system libs and then running `bundle install`